# Use array with mouse event

Tags: jquery

I want to apply mouse events for 114 divs. There are lots of condition for one div. I wrote for one div but there are about 900 lines. If I want to do that for 114 divs it will be really difficult and also boring. I tried examples below but didn't work.

```
var abc= new Array();
abc[0] = ".ABC";
abc[1] = ".DEF";

$(abc).mouseenter(function() {
    Some code
});
```

or

```
for (var a=0;a<114;a++) {
   $(abc[a]).mouseenter(function() {
      Some code
   });
}
```

or

```
while (var a=0;a<114;a++) {
    $(abc[a]).mouseenter(function() {
       Some code
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to define every events one by one. Give all of divs a class and select by the class name:
[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/XYf2W/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="mydivs"></div>
<div class="mydivs"></div>
<div class="mydivs"></div>
....
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.mydivs').mouseenter(function() {
    // grab current div by $(this)
});
```

Comment: are you sure you want to define 114 times the same function instead of refer always to the same

Comment: @Siamak.A.M Oh. I've been working all day. I couldn't think that. :)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The better solution is probably to just put a common class on all the elements that you want the same event handler on, or (if you show us your HTML), you can perhaps use a single delegated event handler.  But, if you insist on setting up separate event handlers for every item in the array, you can do this:

```
$(abc.join(", ")).mouseenter(function() {
    // you can access whatever object triggered the event
    // with the value in this
});
```